# replacing escape character with double qoutes in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have the following string in a variable called,

s:

```
[{\"roleIndex\":0,\"roleID\":\"c1_r0_23\",\"roleName\":\"Chief Executive\"},                       
{\"roleIndex\":1,\"roleID\":\"c1_r1_154\",\"roleName\":\"Chief Operator\"}]
```

and I'm trying to replace \" with " with the following command:

```
   s.ToString().Replace("\"", """");
```

but this is not working.

What is the correct syntax in c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

if you have a string containing `"`, when you view this string in the Visual Studio immediate window it will display it as `\"`. That does **not** mean that your string contains a backslash! To prove this to yourself, use `Console.WriteLine` to display the actual value of the string in a console, and you will see that the backslash is not there.

Here's a screenshot showing the backslash in the immediate window when the string contains only a single quote.

[image: backslash in immediat window]

**Original answer**

Three things:

- Strings are immutable. Replace doesn't mutate the string - it returns a new string.
- Do you want to replace a quote `"\""` or a backslash followed by a quote `"\\\""`. If you want the latter, it would be better to use a verbatim string literal so that you can write `@"\"""` instead.
- You don't need to call `ToString` on a string.

Try this:

```
s = s.Replace(@"\""", "\"");
```

See it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/jlCnu).

Comment: I tried your solution but I'm still not able to replace the backslash and double quote with just a double quote.

Comment: @MdeVera: As you can see I linked to an online compiler that demonstrates my program works. I would guess that you don't actually have the characters in your string that you think you do. How are you looking at the string? Are you viewing it in the source-code? The debugger? Or using Console.WriteLine to display  the string? Can you provide a small but compilable program demonstrating the problem you have, similar to the program I linked to in my answer?

Comment: I'm just debugging and viewing my results in the Immediate window.

Comment: I don't plan on displaying the data out since my next steps is to loop through the array to insert the data into  database.

Comment: @MdeVera: Your strings **are** correct. You don't need to replace anything. It's the debugger displaying them "incorrectly" that is confusing you. The only point of using Console.WriteLine is that you need to convince yourself that your strings are actually correct, because I'm fairly sure you won't take my word for it without seeing it for yourself. Just try it and you will see what I mean. Once you are convinced that you don't have a problem you can remove the WriteLine again.

Answer (score 7):

Try `s.ToString().Replace(@"\""", "\"")`.

The `@` tells C# to interpret the string literally and not treat `\` as an escape character. `"\""` as the second argument uses `\` as an escape character to escape the double quotes.

You also don't need to call `ToString()` if `s` is already of type `string`.

Last but not least, don't forget that string replacement is not done in place and will create a new string. If you want to preserve the value, you need to assign it to a variable:

```
var newString = s.ToString().Replace(@"\""", "\"");
// or s = s.Replace(@"\""", "\"");  if "s" is already a string.
```

Comment: @MarkByers You're absolutely right. Had a typo there. Fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the link to ideone.com/O0bne and get compilation error .....where do you have to put the extra quote?

Comment: @MdeVera I updated my post and it contains correct code now. The ideone link only showcases the error I originally made.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, you need to escape your quote marks and your backslash like so:

`s.ToString().Replace("\\\"", "\"");`

Otherwise it will cat your strings together and do the same as this (if you could actually use single quotes like this):

`s.ToString().Replace('"', "");`

(your second string has four quotes... that's why you're not getting a compile error from having """)

Comment: I tried s.ToString().Replace('"', "");

and get The best overloaded method match for 'string.Replace(char, char)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @MdeVera right, that's why I put that you can't actually do that.  I was just giving a simplified example of what it is equivalent to.